# Compare unequal text parts in natural language processing

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have two texts, one which is read in from a DOCX file and the other from a TXT file. The layout of the DOCX file is like this:

> {NAME}
>
> {ADDRESS}
>
> Dear Mr. Doe,
>
> In spite of your application on our website, we regret to inform you
>   that you don't get the job.
>
> {END}
>
> TheCompany
>
> Registered under number 12345

The layout of the TXT file is the same, but whatever is in brackets is filled in, which makes it impossible to just compare string one on one. It would look like this:

> Jessy
>
> Hillington road 23
>
> Dear Mr. Doe,
>
> In spite of your application on our website, we regret to inform you
>   that you >don't get the job.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> TheCompany
>
> Registered under number 12345

I tried to split the text parts and compare those parts with each other. So a simple:

```
' '.join(text1.split(split_after)[1:]).split(split_before)[0]
```

which is for the DOCX and the same for text2 (TXT) and then compare it. But as the sentence can change, so that it starts with

> Despite of your application on our website (...)

which then breaks all the code. Imagine this scenario for DOCX files up to 20 pages. I need something more useful and programmable.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what your error or question are, but a general solution to the challenge I think you're describing:

Tokenize, then chunk your expressions and compare the number of matching chunks.

Same technique on ngram chunks for single or few-word values.

Comment: You would not get a match, I have tried it already. The chunks would be unequal.

Comment: Then you're not doing it right. Trigram chunks would definitely return a match in the situation provided. Post your code if you need help with it.